# Access database in non-Activity class

Tags: android, sqlite

I have some class (**SomeClass.class**). I want to have some static methods in it like **getAllDatabaseItems**, getTableItems, insertNewRecord and so on.

If I do it this way

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

- I need to extend Activity (but still can't use it in static methods) or pass a "db" variable in every single method (from "caller activity") which is pretty bulky.

What's the solution so I can from some class call **SomeClass.getAllDatabaseItems()**?

**@MobileDev123** So I still need to extend Activity (because of the method **openOrCreateDatabase**)?
If I have this class (which isn't actually an activity, I don't use it that way)

```
public class Partner extends Activity {
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public Partner(Context mContext) {
    myContext = mContext;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, myContext.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + PARTNER_TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME + " VARCHAR);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ADDRESS_TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PARTNER_ID + " INT, " + ADDRESS + " VARCHAR, " + CITY + " VARCHAR);");
}
```

And then call it from some of my activites like this

```
    Partner newPartner = new Partner(this);
    partnersItems = newPartner.getAllItems();
```

I get an NullExceptionError on line 4 (Partner.class) - why? If I use static reference on

```
MODE_PRIVATE => (Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

again it's not working.

**@Falmarri** same with static, if I pass in "this" argument (from some caller class) and receive it as an Context argument in my static method still can't successfully create/open my database (see lines before)

Comment: @svbee As far as my knowledge says you are having atleast one service or activity... It may call your class directly or in call hierarchy.. (i.e `activity-->A-->B-- --->your Class`)... in this case you have to pass on `context` to all the classes. If your class has any View control, you can get View.getContext();

Comment: @svbee my understanding says that you need a context object in your class, and this is how i do when i have such kind of problems. May be there are better answers for that, but till then you can use it.. it works for me.

Comment: Edited my answer, have a look...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be an activity or service which calls your class, what you can do is pass `this` at your convenient time. (I prefer to pass it in constructor).

On receiving hand use the context instant.

E.g From `MyActivity` class you can call `createDatabase(this)` or `new DataServices(this)` but in `DataServices` class the argument type must be `context` instead of `MyActivity`.

Now you have the context parameter and you can use it in the way you want including calling `openOrCreateDatabase()` .

**Edit** : Adding the code

from Main.java

write

```
DataBase database = new DataBase(this); //This will pass an instance of main. Which is eventually the subclass of Context.java
```

**In DataBase class**: you don't need to extend activity there. In constructor defination

`public DataBase(Context context);` 
//If you are using eclipse and rely on some automated tools you can see something like Main main. But use these line, so you can call it from any activity or service by passing this.

define a field of Context class, and refer it to the context arg.

Like `this.localContext= context;`

And by using localContext variable you can call openOrCreateDataBase column.

**ADDITION**: If you have any control (subclass of view) attached to this you can instantiate DataBase  by calling `new DataBase(view.getContext());`

I hope this will help you.... in case any more help needed feel free to comment below.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? I'm still not getting it right (obviously) :/ Still getting Null error.

Comment: why not? but before this I think I need your help. 1. What is the class name which starts your application. Is this an activity or service? 2. I need your class structure... From starting point of your activity to the class. Don't forget to mention if any view control invokes the class in which you want to create database.

Comment: 1. It's a regular activity (Main.java - class Main extends Activity) 2. To keep it simple - I just have another public class (DatabaseOptions.java - class DatabaseOptions extends Activity) in which I would like to have all options related to my database so I can call it from any other Activity class (not just Main.java) when I need to. So just two classes, one is regular activity Main.java (which displays UI and so on) and the other one DatabaseOptions.java which should care about all my database operations.

Comment: Isn't performing `this.localContext= context;` bad practice? Something called holding the context or context leaking? Isn't it better to pass it each time it is necessary thus making the class stateless and not holding a reference to context?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a context. Use SQLiteDatabase static methods:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
public static SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

or:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to do this directly. I have struggled with this myself, but each application uses a different database handle, so Android needs to know how to grab it (a Context) when you get the handle from that oh so convenient:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = (SQLiteDatabase)(new SQLOpenHelperDerivedClass(this)).getReadableDatabase();
```

Perhaps you can figure out how go around SQLOpenHelper and use a hardcoded path to the database. There's probably a whole bunch of helpful stuff that SQLOpenHelper does for you that you'd be giving up though. I imagine that it's probably key to being cross device.

Comment: `Perhaps you can figure out how go around SQLOpenHelper and use a hardcoded path to the database` Nope.

Answer (score 0):

You need a context. If you want to do this in a static method, it has to take in a context